# Only insert not existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table `price` with columns `id,item_name,date,price`.
There can be multiple prices for an `item_name`, for example:

```
ID          item_name          date          price
320           item1         01-04-2022       1.40
321           item1         02-04-2022       1.3
322           item1         03-04-2022       1.42
323           item2         03-04-2022       2.54
324           item2         04-04-2022       2.6
```

This data comes from an `API` and my `ID` is autoincrement.
I now have a script which runs multiple times and always fetches this API. Problem is, that the `API` returns the same data every time, so If I run a normal Insert every time the script executes, I would have duplicate entries like this (note `ID`):

```
ID          item_name          date          price
325           item1         01-04-2022       1.40
326           item1         02-04-2022       1.3
327           item1         03-04-2022       1.42
328           item2         03-04-2022       2.54
329           item2         04-04-2022       2.6
```

What would be the proper SQL-Way of inserting only rows that don't have such `date` and `item_name`?

Comment: What scripting language are you using? Basically I would retrieve the latest prices from the databases, compare those with the prices from the API, and only insert prices that have changed.

Comment: thats, what I have thought of too, but the total amount of eyntries in `price` is about 16mio, which would always take a lot of time to query it

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a lot... you need to be efficient. In the end you have to do something like this.

Comment: Inserting data row by row is not efficient if you have 16moi rows of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use exists logic to block duplicate inserts from happening:

```sql
INSERT INTO price (item_name, date, price)
SELECT  -- your data here
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM price
    WHERE date = <date to be inserted> AND
          item_name = <item to be inserted>
);
```

Another option might be to put a unique index on `(date, price)`.  This would then result in an exception upon inserting a duplicate.  This option might make the most sense when you don't expect such duplicates to happen very often.

Comment: can you give an example for `-- your data here`?

Comment: `SELECT 'item1', '2022-04-01', 1.40` ... which would fail using my answer, since a record with this date and item name already exists.